# Exercise 14.12 of Jech's book

Tags: set-theory

I'm dealing with the chapter about forcing in Jech's book and I need some help with the second part of exercise 14.12. How can I prove the following equality?
$$\Vert (\forall y\in x)\,\phi(y)\Vert=\prod_{y\in dom(x)}x(y)\Rightarrow \Vert\phi(y)\Vert$$

The other equality of the exercise is clear but I'm stuck in this.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Your question is not clear enough.

Comment: @Samrat: No, it's quite clear.

Comment: For the sake of being self-contained, can you write the full statement of the exercise?

Comment: Well if I have to see the question from the book then of course it is clear, but otherwise it is a little unclear to me.

Comment: @Samrat: Are you familiar with forcing using Boolean-valued model?

Comment: @Clement: That is the full statement from the exercise. The first part is essentially the same for bounded existential quantifier.

Comment: Oh, ok. I am not familiar with that model. Sorry then.

Comment: @AsafKaragila: OK. Same comment as Samrat above -- my bad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**HINT:** Recall that $(\forall y\in x)\phi(y)$ is really a shorthand for $\forall y(y\in x\rightarrow\phi(y))$. Now use the definition of $\|\forall y\ \psi(y)\|$.

Comment: Thank you for the hint! :)